# How to add new components in a managed package using SFDX

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

I was going thru the process of creating a managed package from dx as described in this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTTbymAAtAg). Now if i added a new field to an object already added in managed package then packaged using the command `sfdx force:package1:version:create` then the field is added into the package because of the dependency.

But when I added a new aura definition bundle, it wasn't added automatically to the package and there was no sfdx way of doing this either that I could find. Can someone please provide some details on how to add the components to an already existing package? or the only way currently is to add the components to the package from the UI?